# Failed to boot : create volatile files and directories, enable support for additional executables binary formats and LSB: AppArmor initialization

Tags: boot, disk, df

I get these errors whenever I boot the machine:

```
[failed] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[failed] Failed to start Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
[failed] Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
```

Then I entered the recovery mode and checked the root disk with `df -h`, but there is not a disk full problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Add acl option in fstab**

Edit `/etc/fstab` as root.

For example, your fstab rows should looks like:

```
/dev/sdb6  /media/data     ext3    user,noauto,acl  0  0
```

**Move journal.back to journal**

Hit the following as root:

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.service
cd /var/log
ls journal.bak
rm -rf journal
mv journal.bak journal
systemctl start systemd-journald.service
```